# Is it possible to BOLD a word in a TextMeshPro Text String with script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the question asked. Is it possible to BOLD a word in a `TextMeshPro string` with C# script in Unity?

This is part of my code looks like this, with the string variables obtained from the previous menu.

```
public string tempCurrentTeam = "CurrentTeam";
public string roundDivision = "Primary";
public string roundTitle = "Perliminary Round 1";

public TextMeshProUGUI RoundHeaderText;

...
RoundHeaderText.text = ("Active score for: " + tempCurrentTeam + "'s" + " - " + roundDivision + " " + roundTitle);
```

The output to display I would like to look like this. Displayed as a header for the respective scene.

Active score for: **CurrentTeam's** - Primary Preliminary Round 1

I probably don't mind if I need to build the header as three TMP text blocks, if that's the easiest way to go.

Comment: yes you can - it has a markup language. you can set colours and all sorts.. exactly like in the inspector using code..

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TMP accepts rich text, this means that you can simple add a

```
"<b>your bold text</b> - your non bold text"
```

on its text

```
RoundHeaderText.text = $"Active score for: <b>{tempCurrentTeam}'s</b> - {roundDivision} {roundTitle}";
```

Comment: ouh, sorry, stack has converted my rich text to bold... just type <b> and </b> and your text will be bold

Comment: Tried that, and you get these errors: _Assets\Scripts\ScoreManager.cs(74,57): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'_ & _Assets\Scripts\ScoreManager.cs(74,85): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '/'_ assuming this is how it would be done `RoundHeaderText.text = ("Active score for: " + <b> tempCurrentTeam + "'s" </b> + " - " + roundDivision + " " + roundTitle);`

Comment: But can can do the in a C# script text string (edit fixed grammar)

Comment: You typed quite wrong... "Active score for: <b>tempCurrentTeam's</b> - roundDivision  roundTitle"

Comment: No! If you read the script correctly, `tempCurrentTeam` , `roundDivision` & `roundTitle` are `string` names. The example text uses below the script block uses the `string` values as seen at run time. (I'm guessing you need to kindle remove the -1 negative vote, please).

Comment: No mate, the < b> and < /b> should be used inside a string, its a rich text, it will make process on top of string -  $"Active score for: <b>{tempCurrentTeam}'s</b> - {roundDivision}  {roundTitle}";

Comment: Ahh, now that was a much more helpful answer. I have never written a string that way before in Unity. If you put that is as an answer, I will make it as solved.

Comment: Just to clarify, its not from unity, the $ symbol that allows us to mix string and variable are from C# and the rest is rich text symbols, so you use it basically everywhere

Comment: just fyi the `$""` is called [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) ;) And you might need to [enable richtext support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObjectUIText.html#extra-settings) in the TMP component first ;) Also [not all RichText Tags are supported](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/RichTextSupportedTags.html) but Unity